# How to set Chrome as default browser for Java installation

Tags: firefox, java, google-chrome, settings

When going into the Java Control Panel by executing the following command in Terminal:

```
ControlPanel
```

And going to the `Advanced` tab, I see that at the bottom it says:

[image: Command to Launch Default Browser setting]

But I have set my default browser on my system to Google Chrome, and do not wish to use Firefox, so what file path do I change this to to set Google Chrome as my Java installation's default browser?

I looked in my `/usr/bin/` folder where the `Firefox.sh` file is located that my Java installation's settings are pointing to, and I found that two Google Chrome files do exist there, one called `google-chrome` and the other `google-chrome-stable`, so do I change it to point to one of these?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

In Terminal the output of the command `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `google-chrome-stable`.

Alternatively, the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` can be used as well if you want fancy options to be given to your browser.

Just `less` the smallest `.desktop` file you can find in that directory to get a look and feel for the contents before you tackle something like `google-chrome-stable.desktop`.